# How to get ListView items on button click?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` with a `CheckBox` and an `EditText`. I want to get the name and `EditText` value of the checked `CheckBoxes` on a `Button` click. How can I do that?

My getView() method:

```
@Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.scrap_list_row_item, parent, false);
        final EditText kg = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editText1);
        final CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
        final TextView txtKg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        final float scale = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        cb.setPadding(cb.getPaddingLeft() + (int)(10.0f * scale + 0.5f),
                cb.getPaddingTop(),
                cb.getPaddingRight(),
                cb.getPaddingBottom());
        //cb.setText(modelItems[position].getName());
        cb.setText(arrayScrapItems.get(position).getItemName());

        cb.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

               @Override
               public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,boolean isChecked) {
                   if(isChecked)
                   {
                      // Toast.makeText(context, "You checked " + arrayScrapItems.get(position).getItemName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_background_active);
                       kg.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.kg_box));
                       txtKg.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
                       kg.setFocusable(true);
                       kg.setEnabled(true);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //Toast.makeText(context, "You unchecked " + arrayScrapItems.get(position).getItemName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       cb.setButtonDrawable(R.drawable.checkbox_background);
                       kg.setBackgroundResource((R.drawable.kg_box_inactive));
                       txtKg.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#D3D3D3"));
                       kg.setFocusable(false);
                       kg.setEnabled(false);
                   }
               }
           }
        ); 

        return convertView;
```

Comment: There so many tutorials for checkbox with ListView

Answer (score 0):

As ListView recycles it's views you cannot, at the event of the button click go through all list items and see if they are checked or not, because there are only so much views as rows are visible in your list. E.g. if you list has 1000 rows and 20 of them can be shown on screen at the same time, your ListView only has 20 Views (i.e. 20 CheckBoxes and 20 EditTexts) and it is up to your ListAdapter implementation to fill them with the correct data of any of the 1000 rows, depending on how far the user has scrolled the list.

Therefore you will have to keep track of the checked rows and it's texts in some kind of off-screen model.

And when you have all that information in a model you can easily access it, that mentioned  button is clicked.

So, first of all, you will need to change your code in a way that you only create a new view if `convertView` is null. If it is not null, you just update it's View's states to the state of the row at the given `position`. This state should come from your off-screen model.

Hope this answer brings you on the right track, in any case you should get familiar with the way ListViews recycle views.